# How to change "Call Waiting" programmatically in iOS (jailbreak device)?

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, cydia-substrate

I wan't to turn on/off the call waiting feature of iPhone (that can be found at `Settings > Phone > Call Waiting`) programmatically.

What I have figured out is that the phone settings calls `-setCallWaitingEnabled:specifier:` method from `PhoneSettingsCallWaitingController` class found [here](https://github.com/limneos/classdump-dyld/blob/6a728355e388dc6c214bd9aa618622eeb94f79aa/iphoneheaders/iOS7.0.3/System/Library/PreferenceBundles/MobilePhoneSettings.bundle/PhoneSettingsCallWaitingController.h). I found it in `/System/Library/PreferenceBundles/MobilePhoneSettings.bundle/Call Waiting.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>id</key>
    <string>com.apple.preferences.phone.call-waiting</string>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSGroupCell</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>cell</key>
            <string>PSSwitchCell</string>
            <key>get</key>
            <string>callWaitingEnabled:</string>
            <key>label</key>
            <string>Call Waiting</string>
            <key>set</key>
            <string>setCallWaitingEnabled:specifier:</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Call Waiting</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I loaded the bundle manually and initialized the above class and called the method I said but nothing happens. Here's the code:

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PreferenceBundles/MobilePhoneSettings.bundle"];
BOOL success = [b load];
if (success)
{

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n Bundle load successfull! \n\n\n\n ");
    Class PhoneSettingsCallWaitingController = NSClassFromString(@"PhoneSettingsCallWaitingController");
    id tc = [[PhoneSettingsCallWaitingController alloc] init];

    [tc setCallWaitingEnabled:0 specifier:0];

} else NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n Bundle load failure! \n\n\n\n ");
```

I don't know if I'm in the correct path. Is there another way to turn on/off the Call Waiting setting?

Comment: This looks like a UI controller that's driven from data obtained from the network. To disable call waiting you need to use an SS code. The full list of codes is at: http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/122000_122099/122030/10.00.00_60/ts_122030v100000p.pdf

Comment: @Petesh Thanks for the answer. I could't find anything about running SS code. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No idea, probably via the modem interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declarations for `CoreTelephony.framework` private APIs

```
CF_EXTERN_C_BEGIN

CF_EXPORT CFNotificationCenterRef CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
CF_EXPORT void CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterRef center, const void *observer, CFNotificationCallback callBack, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior suspensionBehavior);

CF_EXPORT void CTSettingRequest(NSDictionary* dict);
CF_EXPORT void CTSettingSave(NSDictionary* dict);

CF_EXPORT NSString* kCTSettingCallClassVoice;
CF_EXPORT NSString* kCTSettingTypeCallWaiting;
CF_EXPORT NSString* kCTSettingType;
CF_EXPORT NSString* kCTSettingCallClass;
CF_EXPORT NSString* kCTSettingEnabled;

CF_EXTERN_C_END
```

Setting requests and saves are done asynchronously. Results will be sent to telephony center callback:

```
void SettingCallback(CFNotificationCallback center, void* observer, NSString* name, const void* objec, NSDictionary* userInfo)
{
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"kCTSettingRequestSuccessNotification"])
    {
        //Setting request results are in 'userInfo' argument
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"kCTSettingRequestErrorNotification"])
    {
        //Setting request error
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"kCTSettingSaveSuccessNotification"])
    {
        //Setting saved
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"kCTSettingSaveErrorNotification"])
    {
        //Setting save error
    }
}

...

CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault(), NULL, SettingCallback, NULL, NULL, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

Request call waiting setting:

```
CTSettingRequest(@{@"STSettingTypeUniqueIdentifier" : kCTSettingTypeCallWaiting,
                   kCTSettingCallClass : kCTSettingCallClassVoice, 
                   kCTSettingType : kCTSettingTypeCallWaiting});
```

Save call waiting setting (in this case, enabled):

```
CTSettingSave(@{@"STSettingTypeUniqueIdentifier" : kCTSettingTypeCallWaiting,
                kCTSettingCallClass : kCTSettingCallClassVoice, 
                kCTSettingType : kCTSettingTypeCallWaiting, 
                kCTSettingEnabled : @YES});
```

Comment: @crekerThank you very much. I think there is a little problem in your answer. I think there should be `extern "C"` before the first 4 lines in CoreTelephony declarations in your answer.

Comment: I have a question too:How can I find the other strings for changing other settings? How did you find these functions?

Comment: You need `extern "C"` only if you use those declarations from obj-c++ code. Otherwise it's not needed.

Comment: I wrote that code using disassembly of preference bundle that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @crekerThanks! I'm using objc (I'm compiling with Xcode and iOSOpenDev so I guess it's objc!) and if I don't put the `extern "C"` it gives me a error. Do you know any good references for starting disassembly in iOS?

Comment: If your source files have *.mm extension then they're obj-c++ and require `extern "C"` in order for linker to find the right symbols. Obj-c doesn't need it. It all due to how name mangling is done. It differs in C and C++. As for references, sorry, don't know of anything like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56795/discussion-between-user3519705-and-creker).